# How to have check user input using scanner without having scanner prompt multiple times

Tags: java

So im writing a couple methods that require the user to input what hour(1-24) they want. I need however to check whether they enter in an int, and a number between 1-24. The problem is that the scanners are called multiple times if sent to the error statement. I don't know how to do this without having these issues.

```
public static int getHour(Scanner scan){
        int hour=0;
        System.out.println("Enter the hour for the showtime (1-24):");
        do{
            if((!scan.hasNextInt())||((hour=scan.nextInt())<1)||(hour>24)){
                System.out.println("Enter a valid number");
                scan.next();
            }  else{
                return hour;
            }           
        }while((!scan.hasNextInt())||(hour<1)||(hour>24));        
          return hour;
    }
```

Ideally it only prompts one time when entering in a not valid input such as a string or int outside of 1-24. but it prompts twice or sometimes once depending on the order of what incorrect input you put in.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: If there is no next int, the if-statement short-circuits and prints an "invalid input" response. Remove the call to `hasNextInt`

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart What if there isn't a next int?

Comment: @GBlodgett it either waits for the next int or throws an exception if the stream is closed/the input is not an int

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart It looks like the OP is trying to avoid throwing an exception.

Comment: @GBlodgett in that case, they can use something like `nextLine` and check if it's an integer themselves (regex, try-catch `Integer.parseInt`, etc.)

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart That's essentially what `hasNextInt` does. Takes in a token, checks with regex/tries to parse it, and returns true or false accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192532/discussion-between-benjamin-urquhart-and-gblodgett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering this problem because `.hasNextInt()` does not advance past the input, and `.nextInt()` only advances if translation is successful. A combination of loops and if-statements can thus cause confusion as to whether or not the scanner will advance. Here's your method rewritten to have the scanner prompt only once for each bad input:

```
public int getHour(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.printf("%nEnter the hour for the showtime (1-24): ");
    while (true) {
        input = scan.next();
        entry = -1;
        try {
            entry = (int)Double.parseDouble(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Ensures error is printed for all bad inputs
        }
        if (entry >= 1 && entry <= 24) {
            return entry;
        }
        System.out.printf("%nEnter a valid number: ");
    }
}
```

I prefer to use an infinite loop in this case, but as that can be dangerous, receive it with caution. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why `entry = (int)Double.parseDouble(input);`? Why not just `entry = Integer.parseInt(input);`?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(input)` will work perfectly fine. I use `(int)Double.parseDouble(input)` so that inputs like 3.0 don't throw an error and inputs like 14.62 are simply rounded down. It's entirely optional.

Comment: Yes it will certainly work, it just seems odd to me. I wouldn't expect someone to input 14.62 for the time of a show. Maybe that's just me though

Comment: Haha, I suppose you're right about that. I thought to include it because it expands the range of allowable inputs while still ensuring that they all at least sort of make sense. It definitely is a little odd in this context though.